# Check spelling as you type for macOS

Tags: macos, spell-checker, macbook

I spend many days trying to find an app for macOS that would check my spelling as I type and warn me with a sound that a word was misspelled. [tinySpell+](http://tinyspell.numerit.com/) is what I use on my PC and it is great. I with they will make the app for macOS as well.

**Must have** features that I am looking for:

- Checks spelling in any Windows application
- Checks spelling on-the-fly (alerts if the last typed word was misspelled)
- Checks spelling of text that is copied to the clipboard
- Allows you to add words to the dictionary
- Optionally beeps on error (beep sound can be easily set to any wav file)
- Optionally displays a spelling tip
- Opens replacements list with a simple mouse click or a hot-key
- Optionally copies the selected replacement word to the clipboard
- Optionally inserts the selected replacement word into the document
- Provides easy access to on-line web services (Search, Dictionary, Thesaurus, Encyclopedia)
- Easy Enable/Disable
- Uses little system resources

**Nice to have**:

- Allows you to specify applications for which tinySpell is disabled or enabled
- Supports Hunspell dictionaries in many languages
- Remembers the last error (even if it is not the last typed word)
- Optionally displays a spelling tip with instant correction
- Includes a clipboard spell checker that shows all spelling errors in the clipboard's text in a single glance, and allows you to correct them
- Learns your spelling errors replacements and offers you better suggestions
- Allows you to add auto-replacements to the dictionary
- Allows you to add a list of words to the dictionary
- A scheduled Import/Export of the words added to the dictionary allows easy backup and synchronization of the dictionary with other users on a network
- Automatically switches dictionary according to current language (see Dictionaries below)
- Adds "Translation" to the on-line web services mentioned above (Search, Dictionary, Thesaurus, Encyclopedia)
- Allows you to easily choose the default on-line service in each category from a list of services, or add new services to the category
- Allows you to open a small bar on your desktop that lets you enter text and search for on-line information
- Provides the following additional options:

  - Check Capitalization (proper nouns, etc.)
  - Mixed CaSe is an error
  - Ignore UPPERCASE words
  - Ignore words with numbers
  - Ignore Internet & email addresses and file names
  - Ignore escape sequences (words that start with user specified escape characters)

I copied most of those features from [tinySpell+](http://tinyspell.numerit.com/#features) website. You could see examples there.